# Standard practice error handling for partial data uploads in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Would like to know what (if any) the standard / best-practice way is for handling failed / partial data uploads to firestore DB.

For example, suppose a user needs to upload to two different collections via something like

```
let res = undefined
let docID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
try {
    res = await firebase.firestore().collection('someCollection')
        .doc(docID)
        .set(someData)
} catch (error) { console.error(`Some message ${res}`) }

try {
    res = await firebase.firestore().collection('someOtherCollection')
        .doc(docID)
        .set(someOtherData)
} catch (error) { console.error(`Some message ${res}`) }
```

and that for whatever reason, the program successfully writes to someCollection, but *not* to someOtherCollection. How should this be handled? Should we attempt to roll back what *has* been written (via the catch blocks) or wait until the end of upload attempts and *add / upload* an additional flag to the document and only treat data as valid in the future if it has this flag? Something else?

** Realize that this is close to some [Questions to Avoid Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), but in this case am asking specifically for Firestore API (eg. any functions / objects within the `firestore()` API that is specifically intended to handel these cases) and best practices (if there *are* any in the wider world (pretty new to using Firebase / Firestore)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Firestore [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to ensure that all the documents have updated atomically.  This will ensure that all of the documents are updated, or none of them.

From the referenced docs:

> Cloud Firestore supports atomic operations for reading and writing data. In a set of atomic operations, either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied.